# How can I choose a random value of each data attribute together to choose a random cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically created table and have given each cell row and column attributes to give them numbers between 0-9(10X10 table) called data-x, data-y.
I want to select a random data-x, and data-y (that has a class of empty) and then assign that cell a another class.
I know that I could do it in an easier way by randomly selecting just the cell itself but for some reason it needs to be done this way.

I made variables for random numbers between 0-9 but don't really know how they can connect to my data-x/y in order to do the above.

Could anyone give me advice on the simplest way to do this?

Thanks

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
    var tblB = document.createElement('TBODY');
    table.appendChild(tblB);
    var num = [1];
   
    for (var i = 0; i <10; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('TR');
        tblB.appendChild(tr);
        $(tr).attr('data-x', i)

        for (var j=0; j<10; j++) {
            var td = document.createElement('TD');
            tr.appendChild(td);
            td.append(num++);
        $(td).attr('data-y', j);
        }
    }
    body.appendChild(table);

    var randomRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
        var randomCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
    //How to select a <td> of random data-x,data-y with these     randomRow and randomCol numbers
    //$(td).???
    console.log(randomCol, randomRow);

    //Give all cells a class of empty to start
    $("td").addClass('empty');
    var obs = 0;
    while (obs <= 10) {
        //Find random row and column that has class empty, add             Class(dimmed) to that random row and column (eg. 2 1)
        // var randomRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
        // var randomCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
        // console.log(randomNum + randomCol);
        obs++    
    }
})
```

```css
table td {
    padding: 25px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}

table {
    margin: auto;
}

.dimmed {
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="lightblue">
    <center>
        <h1>Create table in a dynamic way using javascript</h1>
    </center>
    <CENTER>
        <div id=TBL></div>
    </CENTER>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your x and y are always iterative from 0 to 9, you really dont need to add these attributes as your rows and cells are already indexed.

As you seem to use jquery, this simply works without any attributes :

```
var randomRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
var randomCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);

$("#TBL tr:eq(" + randomRow + ") td:eq(" + randomCol + ")").removeClass("empty").addClass("newclass");
```

or for better performance in modern browsers

```
$("#TBL tr").eq(randomRow).children("td").eq(randomCol)
```

Having more info of what you want to achieve, I would better build an array :

```
var cells = array[];
while (cells.length < 10) {
    var cell = Math.random() * 99;
    if(!cells.includes(cell)) cells[] = cell;
}

cells.foreach(function(item) {
    $("#TBL td").eq(item).removeClass("empty").addClass("newclass");
});
```

You build a 10-len array with 10 unique cell number; then for each element of your array you tag the correspondant cell. Note the *td* selector instead of *tr* that will retrieves *all* your cells in a single collection.

Comment: Is the (" + randomRow + ") the part that is using the random number from the variable?
To be a bit more specific, all the cells start off with class of empty and the I need to locate one empty one using row and column indexes, remove the class and then add a new one. I tried out the above code but it didn't seem to work for me, I tried adding a different class instead of empty.

Comment: Just tried removing the #TBL to just have the tr and it worked! Thanks!!

Comment: There is just one issue, I have it in a while loop, butthe number of cells that have their class changed varies, sometimes it is 1 or 2 less than the condition, sometimes it is 1 or 2 more than the condition. Why might this happen?

Comment: @Johnroiste comment #2 : Sorry, I thought that you loaded your table withing the div with TBL id, but you append your table in body instead. But note that if you have another table in the page, her rows will be evaluated as well, its why defining a scope may be a better id.

Comment: @Johnroiste comment #1 : as for data-x and data-y, if all your cells are empty you should avoid to put a class on each cell, and defer the empty css rule on `#scope td`.

Comment: @Johnroiste comment #3 : your random numbers may repeat, and you dont exclude already changed cell. You may need to check if the cell coming out of the hat `hasClass`. Or build an array first with 10 numbers randomized between 0 to 99, see my edit.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Having a look at the edit now. Cheers!